# Execute a curl command if cronjob backup fails

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, cron, postfix-mta

I have a cronjob that takes backup of my DB every 10 min. I want to receive an SMS whenever the backup fails.

Example:

`*/1 * * * * sudo /usr/local/sbin/mysql.sh 2>&1 | curl 'http:www.smsapi.com/user=username&pass=password&text=$errormsg'`

Currently it's not sending any SMS. How can I append error message to curl? (I have also tried this for Email instead of SMS, but that too does not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail:

```
mysql.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Mysql backup" -E user@host
```

cUrl:

```
mysql.sh 2>&1 | curl "http:www.smsapi.com/user=username&pass=password&text=`cat -`"
```

Please note: double quotes instead of apostrophes and backticks with a command to convert std input to a parameter. The conversion is rather primitive, it doesn't URL-quote special characters.

Comment: This sends me a blank email  if there are no errors

Comment: Fixed. Option -E prevents sending empty body.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my email problem. But  no luck with sms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the double-pipe `command || error-handler` for the error-handler to be called only in case the command fails.

I suggest you reverse the logic `command && success-handler` and use a service such as [WDT.io](https://wdt.io) for the success-handler to alert you in case of a missing success (aka failure). The reason is that the cron job itself can fail to run which you'd never find out about when using an error-handler.

As for your second question, how to append the error, you can access the previous return code using `$?`.